# Resizing an element on hover to not move the others around

Tags: html, css, list, resize, hover

> I was trying to make this work but can't find a way. Here's the example I'm working on

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li><img></li>
<li><img></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative}
li{width:100px;height:100px;list-style-type:none;float:left;margin:2px;border: 1px solid #000}
img{}
li:hover{width:150px;height:150px;}
```

And here's the JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/qw2W4/2/**

**How do I have the resizing of the li elements without moving all other elements?**

I would like that to be made without use of JS if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qw2W4/4/
Check out the first element.
I inserted another element which has `position: absolute` and gets scaled on hover.

Comment: It's best if you can solve CSS problems without modifying the markup.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is the best!

Comment: How can this be done with Transition or scaling effect? When there is a time for the transition it goes back to relative positioning too soon before the transition is done

Comment: Making my hover div position:absolute stops it moving everything else around, but in my case these are in-text links, so the hover image always appears on the LH edge instead of at the link location (which is why I originally used position:relative). How do I get the hover image to appear at the link location and still not disturb the surrounding text?

Answer (score 1):

make this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qw2W4/6/)**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
img {
}
li:hover img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the css of li element to

```
li {
  display: inline-block; //or block
  width: 10px; // set a fixed width, 10px for example
}
```

That should work.